# Como funciona o método Save do Model do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos

Salvando:

```
var $newOs    = new OS;
$newOs->date  = date;
$newOs->name  = name;
$newOs->Area  = area;
$newOs->save();
```

Percebam que na última linha tem o `$newOS->save`, no qual não se passa parâmetros. Mas na documentação do Illuminate\Eloquent\Model, tem o método `save()` recebendo parâmetros. 
Suspeito que seja algo no `constructor`, mas não encontrei nada.

Como funciona isso por baixa dos panos se não se passa parâmetro na função?

Não consegui reproduzir isso com Orientação a Objeto.

Ou eu não soube fazer ou é algo que o criador do Laravel fez internamente para isso acontecer.

Comment: O `Illuminate\Eloquent\Model` usa a *Trait* `GuardsAttributes`, essa *trait* trata os atributos que foram inseridos diretamente no objeto, como no seu exemplo. então ele obtém todos os atributos e insere no método `save()`. Bem por cima é isso.

Comment: Acho que vai ajudar: [Documentação sobre insert do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#inserts)

Answer (score 1):

Se você observar bem no código fonte do laravel no GitHub [Model.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1430):

Esse parâmetro do método save é um array de opções isso serve para que você possa desativar o registro de data e hora para essa consulta específica

Você consegue passar por exemplo algo assim:

```
var $newOs    = new OS;
$newOs->date  = date;
$newOs->name  = name;
$newOs->Area  = area;
$newOs->save([
  'timestamps' => false, // Desative o registro de data e hora na inserção e atualização
  'touch'      => false, // Desativa o modelo de relacionamento que toca na classe atual durante o escopo de retorno de chamada especificado.
]);
```

É algo bem comum, olhar a classe do código fonte do Laravel no GitHub vai ajudar a você entende melhor como funciona.

Comment: Embora não tenha sido minha pergunta, achei legal saber disso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Ele é o Commit do MYSQL, você faz todos processos e depois faz o commit para executar a query o save faz exatamente isso, você pode usar ele para Iserir e Editar os dados, o save é a palavra final.

Exemplo de inserir com save:

```
public function insert(Request $request, Model $model){
  $model->nome = $request->nome;
  $model->column = $request->column;
  $model->save();
}
```

Exemplo de update com save:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $model = Model::findOrFail($id);

    $model->nome = $request->nome;
    $model->column = $request->column;
    $model->save();

}
```